# AWS SNS Push notification to backgrounded Android App

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, amazon-sns

I am using AWS SNS with FCM to send notification to Android app.
The payload is as below

```
{"GCM":"{ \"notification\": { \"body\": \"test message\"}}"}
```

This message is delivered ok to Android app when the app is in foreground.
But when app is in background or closed, the message does not appear as display notification on android device.

AWS SNS CloudWatch logs show Status 200 for this message.
FCM debugging logs (EVENTS) on the mobile device also show message received. But I do not get notification on Android device.

Any inputs on this will be really helpful.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? If so, would you please post an answer/update? Thanks.

Comment: If somebody looking for the answer might want to check this too! https://stackoverflow.com/a/31039040/7651583

Answer (score 0):

You may find this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w6rQdurucCk) helpful.

There are two ways to get this to work:

**From SNS UI:**

- Go to sns dashboard after you create endpoint
- Click and publish message then use Custom payload for each delivery protocol (important)
- Replace the default value with example

```html
{"GCM": "{\"notification\": { \"body\": \"Sample message for Android SNS AWS\", \"title\": \"Hello world from AWS SNS\" } }"}
```

[image]

[image]

**From AWS Console:**

- Download AWS CDK, or use console directly from [cloudshell](https://aws.amazon.com/cloudshell/)
- In the cli use sns command

```html
aws sns publish --endpoint-url https://sns.us-west-2.amazonaws.com \
--target-arn arn:aws:sns:your-arn-endpint-here \
--message '{"GCM":"{ \"notification\": { \"body\": \"Sample message for Android or iOS endpoints\", \"title\":\"TitleTest\" } }"}' \
--message-structure json
```

Comment: If somebody looking for the answer might want to check this too! https://stackoverflow.com/a/31039040/7651583